# Javascript dont take changed variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery function with an imagezoom at the big image.
When the big image is changed and i click on it to activate the zoom function, it shows the old image.
I think the variable isnt changed in javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_img(imgurl) {
    image = document.getElementById('preview');
    image.src = imgurl
    imageURL = imgurl
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imageURL = document.getElementById('preview').src;

 $('#ex3').click(function() {
    var imageURL = document.getElementById('preview').src
    $('#ex3')
        .zoom({ on:'click', magnify:1.8, url:imageURL })
        .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
        .css('display', 'block');
 })
});
```

EDIT:
This way the thumbnails will be created:

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex3'>
    <img id="preview" name="preview" src="default.jpg" border="0" align="center"/>
    <span class="zoom-btn"></span>
</span>
<!-- BEGIN thumbs -->
    <div class="thumbnails">
         <img id="thumbimg" onclick="change_img('{PATH}/{thumbs.ID}')" name="img" src="{PATH}/{thumbs.ID}" alt="" />
    </div>
<!-- END thumbs -->
```

In javascript .zoom it should be the changed path at "url:imageURL".
Anyone knows how to get the actual path in imageURL?

Comment: imageURL is not global =/

Comment: ok i think its a stupid question, but how to make it global then?

Comment: declare it before the function, right after the script tag: `var imageURL;`

Comment: add 'var imageURL = ""; above your top function, so it's not contained, also it looks as though you are not declaring image.  this might be causing an error...

Comment: i added the var but same issue... if i make alert(imageURL) in the changefunction, i got the correct changed URL.

Comment: No one has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Will this work?--I'm honestly not sure if this zoom function changes the img source or not. If it doesn't, changing that from here, should be fairly easy. There seemed, from a search, to be several of which you could be using.

```
<span class='zoom' id='ex3' data-src="changedimg.jpg">
    <img id="preview" name="preview" src="default.jpg" border="0" align="center"/>
    <span class="zoom-btn"></span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#ex3').click(function() {
         var newURL = this.data('src')
         $('#ex3')
             .zoom({ on:'click', magnify:1.8, url: newURL })
             .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
             .css('display', 'block'); 
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with jQuery's zoom function, I can edit my answer. I figured given the context it was being called at the right time. Wrong assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its the same issue :)

Comment: Instead of having a whole different div from your "changedImage", why don't you just store it in a data-attribute in the <img > or the <span> node and replace it that way...does that make sense? I can't see any reason why you shouldn't do that, but there may be something I'm not seeing. *changed my answer so you could try out this method*

Comment: Sorry i cant follow your idea. The images are created in a foreach loop for maximum 5 pictures and will be shown under the big one.

Comment: okay, that was hard to understand from what you gave. if you want to give me a more comprehensive example of the html i might be able to help more.

Comment: i added the html part for the thumbnails on top :)

Comment: your code snipped works so far with document.getElementById instead of var newURL = this.data('src'). The only problem is that the "zoomsymbol" is no longer in the corner from the picture, its in the corner of the whole page now. After first klick on the Picture the "zoom-symbol" go in the correct position. The second click let the wrong picture zoom. After click then again, its zoom the correct picture. Thats really crazy o_O

Comment: haha i'm sorry, it's honestly just really hard to contextualize this well without seeing it.